# How to edit/Update BLOB image (PNG)

Tags: java, sqlite, blob

I'm having problems with a method I created to edit a BLOB image. You can find my code bellow (all code is shortened);

```
String edit=txt_gid.getText();
**byte[] e = icon_image1;**
 String sql="update GamesCollector set FrontCover='"+e+"'where GameId='"+edit+"' ";
    ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.execute();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Edited");
    Browse.UpdateTable();
```

This is how I display an image on a JLabel (Swing component);

```
 public static ImageIcon pic1=null;

 String sql="select * from GamesCollector where Title=?";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);


        ps.setString(1, txt_search.getText().toUpperCase().trim());
        rs=ps.executeQuery();

 if(rs.next()){

byte[] datapic = rs.getBytes("FrontCover");
            pic1 = new ImageIcon(datapic);
            front.setIcon(pic1);}
```

This is the code which is causing a problem;

```
static void Edit(){


 try{



        String edit=txt_gid.getText();

        String edit1=txt_title.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        String edit2=cmb_platform.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(edit2==null){edit2="";}

        String edit3=cmb_format.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(edit3==null){edit3="";}

        String edit4=list_genres.getSelectedValue().toString();
        if(edit4==null){edit4="";}

        String edit5=((JTextField)pck_releasedate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText(); 
        String edit6=txt_desc.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        String edit7=txt_developer.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        String edit8=txt_publisher.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        String edit9=txt_series.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        String edit10=txt_barcode.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        String edit11=collection;
        String edit12=cmb_esrb.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(edit12==null){edit12="";}

        String edit13=cmb_pegi.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(edit13==null){edit13="";}

        String edit14 = Integer.toString(rating_slider.getValue());

        **byte[] e = icon_image1;**



        String sql="update GamesCollector set Title=='"+edit1+"',Platform='"+edit2+"',Format='"+edit3+"',Genres='"+edit4+"',ReleaseDate='"+edit5+"',Description='"+edit6+"',Developer='"+edit7+"',Publisher='"+edit8+"',Series='"+edit9+"',Barcode='"+edit10+"',Collection='"+edit11+"',ESRB='"+edit12+"',PEGI='"+edit13+"',Rating='"+edit14+"',FrontCover='"+e+"'   where GameId='"+edit+"' ";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Edited");
        Browse.UpdateTable();


    }

    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    finally {

        try{
            rs.close();
            ps.close();

        }

        catch(Exception e){}

    }

  }
```

}

This method is used to get the path and to convert it into a ByteArray;

```
protected static void AttachImage(){

    JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser("D:\\Downloads\\Software Development\\GameCollector\\Images\\Game");
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File s=chooser.getSelectedFile();
    filename = s.getAbsolutePath();


    try{
    File image = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] bug = new byte[1024];

    for(int readNum; (readNum=fis.read(bug)) !=-1;){
        baos.write(bug,0,readNum);        
    }

     icon_image1=baos.toByteArray();
     icon_image2=baos.toByteArray();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
 }
```

This method is used to save the file;

```
static void Save(){

   try{

        String sql="insert into GamesCollector (GameId,Title,Platform,Format,Genres,ReleaseDate,Description,Developer,Publisher,Series,Barcode,Collection,ESRB,PEGI,Rating,FrontCover,BackCover) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setString(1, txt_gid.getText().toUpperCase().trim());
        ps.setString(2, txt_title.getText().toUpperCase().trim());
        String platform=cmb_platform.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(platform==null){platform="";}
        ps.setString(3, platform);
        String format=cmb_format.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(format==null){format="";}
        ps.setString(4, format);
        String genres=list_genres.getSelectedValue().toString();
        if(genres==null){genres="";}
        ps.setString(5, genres);
        ps.setString(6, ((JTextField)pck_releasedate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
        ps.setString(7, txt_desc.getText().toUpperCase().trim());
        ps.setString(8, txt_developer.getText().toUpperCase().trim());
        ps.setString(9, txt_publisher.getText().toUpperCase().trim());
        ps.setString(10, txt_series.getText().toUpperCase().trim());
        ps.setString(11, txt_barcode.getText().toUpperCase().trim());

        ps.setString(12, collection);

        String esrb=cmb_esrb.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(esrb==null){esrb="";}
        ps.setString(13, esrb);
        String pegi=cmb_pegi.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(pegi==null){pegi="";}
        ps.setString(14, pegi);
        int rating = rating_slider.getValue();
        ps.setString(15, Integer.toString(rating));
        ps.setBytes(16, icon_image1);
        ps.setBytes(17, icon_image2);

        ps.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");
       }

    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    finally {

        try{
            rs.close();
            ps.close();

        }

        catch(Exception e){}

    }
  }
```

When I'm retrieving the data everything works fine.

This method is used to edit the data;

```
static void Edit(){
   try{
        String edit=txt_gid.getText();

        String edit1=txt_title.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        String edit2=cmb_platform.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(edit2==null){edit2="";}

        String edit3=cmb_format.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(edit3==null){edit3="";}

        String edit4=list_genres.getSelectedValue().toString();
        if(edit4==null){edit4="";}

        String edit5=((JTextField)pck_releasedate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText(); 
        String edit6=txt_desc.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        String edit7=txt_developer.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        String edit8=txt_publisher.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        String edit9=txt_series.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        String edit10=txt_barcode.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        String edit11=collection;
        String edit12=cmb_esrb.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(edit12==null){edit12="";}

        String edit13=cmb_pegi.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(edit13==null){edit13="";}

        String edit14 = Integer.toString(rating_slider.getValue());

        byte[] e = icon_image1;



        String sql="update GamesCollector set Title=='"+edit1+"',Platform='"+edit2+"',Format='"+edit3+"',Genres='"+edit4+"',ReleaseDate='"+edit5+"',Description='"+edit6+"',Developer='"+edit7+"',Publisher='"+edit8+"',Series='"+edit9+"',Barcode='"+edit10+"',Collection='"+edit11+"',ESRB='"+edit12+"',PEGI='"+edit13+"',Rating='"+edit14+"',FrontCover='"+icon_image1+"'   where GameId='"+edit+"' ";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Edited");
        Browse.UpdateTable();


    }

    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    finally {

        try{
            rs.close();
            ps.close();

        }

        catch(Exception e){}

    }

  }
```

After an edit, the method won't retrieve any data anymore.

The data is saved when I'm editing it. The problem only occurs when I'm showing it on my graphical interface. All the data will be shown except for the image which shows me a blank area.

How do I solve the issue I'm having?

Comment: Can you post the /minimal/ code that reproduces the problem? I don't want to compile everything just to see that there's an error.

Comment: suppose if we want to save we just use the ps.setBytes(16, icon_image1); but on editting when i call back the icon_image1 it shows me and empty image

Comment: A minimal example would be very helpful.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108043/how-to-update-edit-sqlite-blob

Comment: First verify that the re-loaded image is the same bytes that you saved (i.e. not corrupted). And maybe show us how you are displaying the image, since you say that's the bit that isn't working...

Comment: everything is fine my program is not showing any error... the problem that im facing not is when i want to edit my image

Comment: i have posted a minimal example @Johny Graber

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put the image into the SQL command string:

```
String sql="update ... set ... FrontCover='"+icon_image1+"' ...
```

This does not work with binary data.

To ensure that binary data goes into the database correctly, use parameters, like in your `Save` method.

Comment: can u give me an example.... if im using the ps.setbytes(12, icon_image1) it will give me an error null pointer exception

Comment: can u show me an example because ps.setbytes is only for saving method i really dont know how to code it in editting method

Comment: `ps.setbytes(12, icon_image1);` should be correct. Is `ps` initialized at this point?

Comment: yes it has been initialized...so if i include this ps what do i need to change in my sql statement @CL.

Comment: Well, you need to show more code. Strictly speaking, this is a new question.